# proto3 check if parameter is set

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

since in proto3 all parameters are optional when parameter is not set and message is deserialized then unset parameter holds default value. I can not find a way to check if the parameter has been set or not. Is there any way to find if parameter has been set similary as in proto2? I see that there is a method has_<param_name>() but it is private.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the distinction exists anymore in proto3. You are encouraged to have meaningful defaults.

But if you must, you can use a [singular embedded message](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#embeddedmessage) containing the value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems after Protobuf [3.15.0](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.15.0) you could use `hasField` in C++ again:

According to the CHANGELOG:

> Now Proto3 Oneof fields have "has" methods for checking their presence in
> C++.

Comment: As mentioned, this is only for OneOf fields

Comment: @ClémentJean this is also for fields of message types and for `optional` fields. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322599/23715).

Answer (score 0):

Building upon ramsay's answers, one thing that you can do if you have a real need for `Null` kind of value, is this:

```proto
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

message Test {
  oneof value_or_null {
    string value = 1;
    google.protobuf.NullValue null = 2;
  };
}
```

with the one of you will get the `has_<param_name>()` function back and you will be able to check if you have null or a value. Also this is a safer approach because you cannot set the two fields, the oneof implementation will make sure that potential previous field value get cleared and set the new one.

**Do note however, that evolving oneof fields is trickier than evolving normal fields (you can see the potential problems [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#backwards-compatibility_issues))**

### My recommendations

- I would first make sure that there is a real need for `Null` and thus a real need for oneof.
- I would try to make the default value of each field an invalid value in my business logic (eg: uint32 id with 0 value is invalid and I return an error)

Answer (score 0):

Protobuf 3 C++ generated code implements `has_xxx()` for fields of message types and for `oneof` fields.

Also, starting from [protobuf 3.15](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/10463) the `optional` protobuf keyword is officially supported, and for such `optional` fields the `has_xxx()` member is also generated.